# Using a Variable in a sed command called in Tcl Script for deletion

Tags: tcl

```
set f_d "y"
exec sed {/feature $f_d starts/, /feature $f_d ends/ d} file > temp_file
```

I would like to use the value of `f_d` in the sed command but I'm not able to do that. Someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

The right tool is to use double-quoting instead of brace quoting.

```
exec sed "/feature $f_d starts/, /feature $f_d ends/ d" file > temp_file
```

***BE AWARE*** *that this means you may need to be very careful.* In particular, if your *real* code has backslashes or other Tcl metacharacters in the sed script then you will need to quote those characters.

And you can do the task entirely in Tcl without calling any external programs.